# automatically execute zz after register jump?

Tags: vimrc, normal-mode

whenever you are jumping between marks some of the marks are placed at the bottom of the screen and you have to do `zz` to bring them to the middle.

Is there a way to auto-execute zz after each jump done via the single quote command `('<register>)` ?

something like this :

`nnoremap '<registry> '<registry>zz`

Comment: It's a mark, not a register.

Comment: Welcome to vi SE. What happens when you try your mapping?

Comment: It won't work because it's not a valid vim command (?)

I think this might work : 


`nnoremap '<expr> '. v:register . zz`

Comment: Oh I think I found the answer :

https://old.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/80vutj/how_to_center_screen_after_moving_to_a_mark/duz2t0k/

`nnoremap <expr> ' "'" . nr2char(getchar()) . "zz"`

Comment: If you found the answer, post an answer. You will be able to accept it after 48 hours.

Comment: Sorry I'm being pedantic but you should not edit your question to contain an answer. Instead, scroll all the way down to the textbox with "Your answer" written above it, paste your answer there and then press "Post your answer". It is important for the mechanics of this site and will help other users find good answers.

Comment: I have removed the answer portion of the question. As others said, post your answers in the answers! Self-answers are allowed and encouraged, and separating questions from answers lets us vote independently on each.